# Renaming filename using React Uploady

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, upload

My problem in a nutshell; I am using react uploady component to upload images. The problem I need to rename the files while uploading but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I read all the documentation of react uploady and googled a lot but no luck. There are no relevant examples. There are examples how to rename file while uploading they don't work in this components logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the renaming either on the server or on the client.

On the client you can do it like so:

```js
useRequestPreSend(({ items, options }) => {         
            
      items[0].file.name = "new name";

            return {
               items
            };  
        });
```

If you want to grab the new name from the client and pass it as a param for your server to handle the rename, you can do it like so:

```js
useRequestPreSend(({ items, options }) => {         
            


            return {
              options: {
   params: {
                            newName: getNewName(items[0]),
                        }           
}
            };  
        });
```

The "newName" param will be submitted along with the uploaded file and you can use it on the server to save the file (make sure to sanitize and validate, of course).

In both cases, the hook to use is [useRequestPreSend](https://react-uploady.org/docs/api/hooks/useRequestPreSend/) that allows you to make changes just before the request is sent.